# check box checked state getting wrong in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

My ASP.NET application has two Check-boxes. I want to checked a check-box another check-box checked on condition.The condition is if another check-box is not checked than only is checked otherwise not. For that i have to check that checked state.And this is doing by `**$(chkmanual).is(":checked")**`

Code snipet given below:

```
function UpdateCheck() {
  var chkmanual = $("[id*=chkManual]");
  alert($(chkmanual).is(":checked")); //here i getting always true. 
  if (!$(chkmanual).is(":checked"))
  {                 
     chkmanual.click();
  }
}
```

My check box like:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dgDeviceList" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
     <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%">
        </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
              <tr>
                  <td>
              <ajaxToolkit:ToggleButtonExtender ID="ToggleExManual" runat="server" TargetControlID="chkManual" CheckedImageAlternateText="Check" UncheckedImageAlternateText="UnCheck" UncheckedImageUrl="~/images/empty.png"
CheckedImageUrl="images/checkbox.png" ImageWidth="30" ImageHeight="30" DisabledCheckedImageUrl="~/images/DisableCheckbox.png"                                           DisabledUncheckedImageUrl="~/images/DisableEmpty.png" />
              <ajaxToolkit:ToggleButtonExtender ID="ToggleExPatientOwned" runat="server" TargetControlID="chkPatientOwned" CheckedImageAlternateText="Check" UncheckedImageAlternateText="UnCheck" UncheckedImageUrl="~/images/empty.png"
 CheckedImageUrl="images/checkbox.png" ImageWidth="30" ImageHeight="30" DisabledCheckedImageUrl="~/images/DisableCheckbox.png"DisabledUncheckedImageUrl="~/images/DisableEmpty.png" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkManual" runat="server" Text="Manual" Width="100px" CssClass="chkPosition" Enabled="false" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPatientOwned" runat="server" Text="Patient Owned" Width="130px" onclick="javascript:UpdateCheck();" CssClass="chkPosition" Enabled="false" />
              </td>
            </tr>
           </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
       </FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: why `$("[id*=chkManual]")`?? cant this just be `$("#chkManual]")`

Comment: Because $("#chkManual]") not working as this check box is in the datalist.

Comment: can you paste rendered html and relevant js code here..please..`$("#chkManual")` this should work..typo in comment..`]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/3ty25/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="manual">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="updateCheck(this);">
```

**Jquery**

```
function updateCheck(sender)
{
    if(!$(sender).prev('#manual').prop('checked'))
        $(sender).attr("checked",true);
    else
        $(sender).attr("checked",false); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check it by using a javascript in your asp.net client side code (aspx page).
Try the following code, it is simple and work for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function EnableDisableCB() {
        if (document.getElementById('<%=checkBox1.ClientID%>').checked) {
            document.getElementById('<%=checkBox2.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%=checkBox2.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

above simple script will enable disable your 2nd checkbox depending on your 1st checkbox condition.